# Notepad ++. Find specific text and select the whole line and replace other text

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

Hy,

i am new to notepadd++ and i want to replace some text.
I have specific text in lines like Volume(m3) and want to change IFCLABEL to IFCREAL and delete '.

This I have:

```
#425=IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Volume(m3)',$,IFCLABEL('0.1'),$);
```

I want to get out.

```
#425=IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('Volume(m3)',$,IFCREAL(0.1),$);
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Try `#\d+=.*?'Volume\(m3\).*?\bIFC\KLABEL\b` and replace with `REAL`

Answer (score 0):

You could use for example:

**Find what:**

```
#\d+=.*?'Volume\(m3\).*?\bIFC\KLABEL\b
```

**Replace with:**

`REAL`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NPWJHl/1)

[image]